# npm install different on ci and server

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Im trying to deploy https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example via gitlab, but i keep getting an error when that build is deployed to my server.

My `gitlab-ci.yml` is as follows:

```
image: ubuntu:14.04

before_script:
  - apt-get update -y
  - apt-get install -y libssl-dev libfontconfig build-essential wget python-pip
  - wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.1/install.sh | bash
  - . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
  - nvm install 4.4.6
  - nvm use 4.4.6
  - pip install awscli
  - npm install

deploy:
  script:
    - npm run build
    - sh zip-and-upload-to-s3.sh
```

Then my server checks s3 for new builds, downloads it and extracts it.

When the same is done on my server (except for the upload to s3) it works fine, but when the build is one from the ci server is get the following errors:

```
> react-redux-universal-hot-example@0.9.0 dev /var/www/html
> concurrent --kill-others "npm run watch-client" "npm run start-dev"

module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'rx'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/node_modules/.bin/concurrent:3:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-88-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v4.4.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! react-redux-universal-hot-example@0.9.0 dev: `concurrent --kill-others "npm run watch-client" "npm run start-dev"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
...
```

The only difference between the 2 machines i can see is the `ci` is a docker container and my server is an ec2 instance running the latest ubuntu 14.04 ami.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I seem to have narrowed down the issue to using `zip`.

When using `tar` to compress the files and upload to s3, it works fine, but when using `zip` i get the above mentioned error.

I have also tried `zip -0` and it still causes the problem.